# IBM Watson nl-c training time

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, training-data, nl-classifier

I have a data-set that contains about 14,700 records. I wish to train it on ibm watson and currently i'm on trial version. What is the rough estimate about the time that the classifier will take to train? Each record of dataset contains a sentence and the second column contains the class-name.

Answer (score 2):

For NLC it depends on the type of data, and quantity. There is no fixed time to when it completes, but I have seen a classifier run a training session for nearly a day.

That said, normally anywhere from 30 minutes to a couple of hours.

Watson conversation Intents is considerably faster (minutes). But both use different models, so I would recommend to test both and see the results. Also check how each is scoring when comparing (absolute/relative).

Answer (score 0):

If your operating system is UNIX, you can determine how long a query takes to complete and display results when executed using dbaccess. You can use the time command to report how much time is spent, from the beginning to the end of a query execution. Including the time to connect to the database, execute the query and write the results to an output device.

The time command uses another command or utility as an argument, and writes a message to standard error that lists timing statistics for that command. It reports the elapsed time between invocation of the command and its termination. The message includes the following information:

The elapsed (real) time between invocation and termination of the utility. The real time is divided in two components, based on the kind of processing:
The User CPU time, equivalent to the sum of the tms_utime and tms_cutime fields returned by the times function for the process in which utility is executed.
or,
The System CPU time, equivalent to the sum of the tms_stime and tms_cstime fields returned by the times() function for the process in which utility is executed.

Comment: If you want more information check this [Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21156611)